# Can a template class or function have different datatypes as parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

This might seem as a stupid question but Is it possible for a template class or function to have different datatypes as parameters.

E.g. For a definition;

```
T compare(T n1, V n2, T n3){
...
}
```

If that is not the case, wouldn't it be a good idea?

Comment: Yes, you can have more than one template parameter with different names. Try it out :)

Comment: *Is it possible for a template class or function to have different datatypes as parameters?* Sure! Imagine how boring a template class would be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
template <class T, class U>
T GetMin (T a, U b) {
  return (a<b?a:b);
}
```

(Taken from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)

Comment: I noticed that your url had _oldtutorial_ in it. I think this is a newer version: [http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/) (the relevant part is near the bottom of the page)